# VmWare VDDK: Error when call PrepareForAccess

Tags: vmware

Before backup VM disks on some vCenter's VM that looks ordinal I call  VixDiskLib_PrepareForAccess in my test app but failed with error.

```
 VixDiskLib: VixDiskLib: VixDiskLib_PrepareForAccess: Deactivate Storage VMotion failed. 
Error 3 (One of the parameters was invalid) (Invalid argument: sourceId. 
(Is the disk part of the snapshot you are trying to mount?)) at 6200.
```

On other vCenter instances that I used I haven't see such kind of errors.

Where to investigate to find a clue? Vcenter/ esxi versions? Vcenter setting related to Storage vMotion? Something wrong with VM disks? Any other ideas?